# JNI Java From C Multiple Java Dependencies

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI to call Java from C code. My Java project is dependent on many classes and external jars. I am confused how to package my java project so that it may be called within C.

To my understanding JNI uses a single class file, but if that class is dependent on many other classes, how would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Java from C (and not the other way round), you first start the JVM and then run some Java code. When you start the JVM, you can specify a classpath that would typically include several jar files each containing several Java class. It is by no means restricted to a single class file.

Specifically note the `optionString` below:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  JavaVM *vm;
  JNIEnv *env; 
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  JavaVMOption options[1];   
  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./lib/jarfile1.jar;./lib/jarfile2.jar"; 
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 1;
  jstring jstr; 
  jobjectArray args; 
  jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
  if (res < 0) { 
    printf("Can't create Java VM\n"); 
    exit(1);
    } 
  jclass cls = env->FindClass("YourMainClass");
  if (cls == 0) { 
    printf("YourMainClass class not found\n"); 
    exit(1); 
    } 
  jmethodID mid = 
    env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V"); 
  if (mid == 0) { 
    printf("main() method not found\n"); 
    exit(1); 
    } 
  jstring argString = env->NewStringUTF(""); //empty arg list
  jobjectArray args = 
     env->NewObjectArray(1, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), jstr); 
  if (args == 0) { 
    printf("Out of memory\n"); 
    exit(1); 
    } 
  env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, args); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This answered my question completely. I would up vote you but I do not have a high enough reputation.

Comment: You're welcome. You should be able to mark the answer as the accepted one (check mark left of answer). That's what you're supposed to do with the best answer the answers your question.